# How to set and change duty cycles for PWM code

Tags: c, microcontroller, led, pwm

I am trying to blink the yellow and green LEDs on my CC32xx board. To do that I need to edit some code that was presented to me. I need to set duty for PWM1 to 90%, set duty for PWM2 to 10%, set the sleep(1) function so it sleeps for 1 second, set duty for PWM1 to 0%, set duty for PWM2 to 90%, and create my code in a loop.

So far, I have set PWM1 to 90% of the period and PWM2 to 10% of the period. And changed the value of variable time to 1000000 ms, which is 1 second. How do you change value of PWM1 to 0% and PWM2 to 90% of period after the sleep function executes? Here is my code:

```
/*
 *  ======== pwmled2.c ========
 */
/* For usleep() */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stddef.h>

/* Driver Header files */
#include <ti/drivers/PWM.h>

/* Driver configuration */
#include "ti_drivers_config.h"

/*
 *  ======== mainThread ========
 *  Task periodically increments the PWM duty for the on board LED.
 */
void *mainThread(void *arg0)
{
    /* Period and duty in microseconds */
    uint16_t   pwmPeriod = 3000;
    uint16_t   duty = 0;
    uint16_t   dutyInc = 100;

    /* Sleep time in microseconds */
    uint32_t   time = 1000000;
    PWM_Handle pwm1 = NULL;
    PWM_Handle pwm2 = NULL;
    PWM_Params params;

    /* Call driver init functions. */
    PWM_init();

    PWM_Params_init(&params);
    params.dutyUnits = PWM_DUTY_US;
    params.dutyValue = 0;
    params.periodUnits = PWM_PERIOD_US;
    params.periodValue = pwmPeriod;
    pwm1 = PWM_open(CONFIG_PWM_0, &params);
    if (pwm1 == NULL) {
        /* CONFIG_PWM_0 did not open */
        while (1);
    }

    PWM_start(pwm1);

    pwm2 = PWM_open(CONFIG_PWM_1, &params);
    if (pwm2 == NULL) {
        /* CONFIG_PWM_0 did not open */
        while (1);
    }

    PWM_start(pwm2);

    /* Loop forever incrementing the PWM duty */
    while (1) {
        PWM_setDuty(pwm1, 2700);

        PWM_setDuty(pwm2, 300);

        duty = (duty + dutyInc);

        if (duty == pwmPeriod || (!duty)) {
            dutyInc = - dutyInc;
        }

        usleep(time);
    }
}
```

Comment: To change the duty-cycle to 0, you set the count-control register (`CCR`) value to the max value of the timer period (e.g. the rollover value). The duty-cycle is the percentage of time that power is being applied. So if your timer has 16-bit precision (max 32767) and you have a 50% duty-cycle (`CCR = 16384`) the power is off from `0 - 16383` and on from `16384 - 32767`. To set the duty-cycle to `0` set `CCR = 32767` so there is no on period. Conversely for 100% duty-cycle, set `CCR = 0`.

Comment: For you, you seem to have a timer period of `pwmPeriod = 3000;` so to set a 90% PWM, you would need to set `CCR = 300` so the PWM power is on for 90% of the `3000` tick period. The `CCR` value seems to be your `params.dutyValue`.